# Is this query optimised? - Mutual follows

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

**Is this query optimised?**

I'm trying to get the list of people personA follows who follow personB.

Few thousand of rows right now in the table but growing fast.

Want to make sure the query is performant enough for mysql.

Query:

```sql
select 
  * 
from 
  (
    select 
      * 
    from 
      creator_followers cf 
    where 
      cf.follower_user_id = 'personA' 
      and cf.current_active = 1 
      and cf.current_following = 1
  ) as fo 
  join creator_followers cf 
where 
  fo.creator_user_id = cf.follower_user_id 
  and cf.creator_user_id = 'personB' 
  and cf.current_following = 1 
  and cf.current_active = 1 
order by 
  cf.created_at desc 
limit 
  10 offset 0;
```

Schema:

```sql
create table social.creator_followers
(
    creator_user_id varchar(16) charset utf8 null,
    follower_user_id varchar(16) charset utf8 null,
    current_following bit null,
    current_active bit null,
    created_at bigint null,
    id bigint auto_increment
        primary key
)
```

Comment: No. Subquery `fo` is excess.

Comment: How? Can you please explain

Comment: personB == trump??

Comment: Is `current_following` deliberately tri-state?  (On, Off, NULL)  Suggest making it NOT NULL if appropriate.

Comment: Is this pair UNIQUE?  (creator_user_id, follower_user_id)

Comment: @RickJames (creator_user_id, follower_user_id) is unique, yes current_following should be bi-state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it must be

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM creator_followers cf1
join creator_followers cf2 ON cf1.creator_user_id = cf2.follower_user_id 
where cf1.follower_user_id = 'personA' 
  and cf2.creator_user_id = 'personB' 
  and cf1.current_active = 1 
  and cf1.current_following = 1
  and cf2.current_following = 1 
  and cf2.current_active = 1 
order by cf2.created_at desc 
limit 10 offset 0;
```

Comment: @AbhisekPadhi . . . Is this actually faster than your query?  If so, what is the improvement?

Comment: @GordonLinoff In theory they must produce the same executoin plan and does not differ in execution time. But my query seems to be more clear...

Comment: @Akina . . . I agree with that.  That just doesn't seem to be what the OP asked for.

Comment: @GordonLinoff maybe, I don't know what OP have told about using the word "optimize". Maybe he wants to improve the performance (in this case he must create suitable indices), but maybe he wants the SQL text to be readable and more clear only - why not?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't noticed any execution time difference with my query and @Akina

Answer (score 0):

Based on a Comment, this might provide another speedup.  Replace

```
id bigint auto_increment
        primary key
```

with

```
PRIMARY KEY(creator_user_id, follower_user_id)
```